# Culture info input file c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, csv

I am writing a program that should help make calculations depending on the file that the user imports (csv input file).

For the calculations are right I force the program has operated with a culture "en-US".

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

I read the input file that way

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\data.csv"))
            {   
                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var values = currentLine.Split(';');

                        string a = values[0];
                        string b = values[1];
                        string c = values[2];
                        string d = values[3];
                        string e = values[4];
                        string f = values[5];
                        string g = values[6];
                        string h = values[7];
                        string i = values[8];
                        string j = values[9];
                        string k = values[10];
                  }
                }
```

My worry is that I do not know the language recording of the input file , maybe it is a culture "fr - FR" and I have to ensure that the data separator, the decimal corresponent language "en-US " . Could you explain to me how to determine the language of the input file or how to convert it to make it compatible with the language "en-US "

Comment: Consider where the file originates. Can you do anything when the file is created, like include the culture in the file name or as the first line?

Comment: I can't, the user makes the file with Excel. Its totally transparent for him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. My input file is a 10 columns file with a first header row. The user must write in the first row :

LABEL1 LABEL2 etc... until 10

So, i use the function "between" to find the delimiter.

test is the first line of the file read using a StreamReader. I store the first line into a string.

```
Console.WriteLine(test.Between("LABEL1", "LABEL2"));
```

And now, i know if this is a ";" delimiter i'll replace every "," with a "." and if the delimiter is a "," i dont have to replace any decimal separator because its already a "." etc etc for any delimiter...

Regards

Comment: You must be careful with this kind of transformation not to replace a dot by a comma in text, for instance. For numbers, you can specify the culture to use to parse the string. This will work better with number greater or equal to 1000, since Excel could add the thousands separators in the csv file. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, CSV format is not strictly related to culture. The common separators (`;` or `,`), delimiters (`"`) are unrelated to the culture, even though some tools such as Excel use `,` for en-US version (which can be changed anyway) and `;` for fr-FR.

The best way is to work with those files is to establish a contract ("The library processes CSV files with the following format:"), or take some configuration to handle the file properly.

Otherwise, you'll have to try an heuristic approach by parsing the header and content (if you have a fixed number of column, you may be able to guess the separator) but it has limits.

It's the same problem that one can encounter when trying to figure out what encoding is used in a file (you may also have that problem, a CSV file could be encoded with `UTF-8` or `ANSI` for instance).

(BTW, Excel is an awful tool to handle CSV files, it truncates data and do other weird stuff. Access handles CSV files far better, but people tend to use Excel).

Comment: Yes the input file had 10 columns and X rows. And if i make an window with a textblock with the content of the input file. And a textbox to enter the column separator, after that i can define the decimal separator (if the user enter ";" as column separator every , is a decimal separator, i have to replace every "," with a "." and delete "" ?